# HTML/CSS: Remove outer table borders

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML/CSS which is supposed to float three tables of equal size next to each other (it does).  However, I am trying to remove the box from the outer-most tables in the nested structure.  Due to the CSS for the inner tables and the fact that I need to float the three outer tables next to each other, I've tried `border-collapse`, `border=none`, even `border-color=white`.  What am I missing?

```css
.maintable {
  border: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.tablestyle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 420px;
}

.wide {
  width: 40%;
}

.thin {
  width: 20%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<br>
<br>

<body>
  <table class="maintable">
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>
  <table class="maintable">
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>
  <table class="maintable">
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: The three outer boxes are what I am trying to hide.

[image]

Comment: The code you have is not floating the tables, so its difficult to see what the problem is. Also, please show us where you used `border-collapse`, `border=none` and `border-color=white` so we can see what you were trying to do.

Comment: This HTML with a table in a table like this isn't really valid, but is removing the border from the `.tablestyle` class what you're wanting?

Comment: The `table` element may only contain `caption`, `colgroup`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, or `tr` elements. The name of the attribute is `colspan`, not `col` and `span`. Of course, you don't need a `colspan` attribute if the cell spans a single column. In any case, your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @abney317 Actually I am trying to remove it from `.maintable`

Comment: I just edited the post.  I am trying to remove those three outer boxes.  All of the nested tables are fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove table border by using border attribute

```
<table border="0">
```

```css
       
            .tablestyle {
                width: 420px;
            }
            .wide {
                width: 40%;
            }
            .thin {
                width: 20%;
            }
            td, th {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 2px;
            }
```

```html
<table border="0" class="tablestyle">
                    <th colspan="4"></th>
                    <col span="1" class="wide">
                    <tr><th col span="1" class="thin"></th><th col    span="1" class="thin"></th><th col span="1" class="thin"></th><th col span="1" class="thin"></th></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out this one line `/*border: 1px solid black;*/` on the `.tablestyle`

```css
.maintable {
  border: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.tablestyle {
  border: none;
  /* 1px solid black;*/
  width: 420px;
}

.wide {
  width: 40%;
}

.thin {
  width: 20%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>

<body>
  <table class="maintable">
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>
  <table class="maintable">
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>
  <table class="maintable">
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="tablestyle">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
      <col span="1" class="wide">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
        <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi @Gad I tried that, however, it would need to be removed for `.maintable` not `.tablestyle`.  And, removing it from maintable does nothing, for some reason.  It still shows.

Comment: @sbagnato the easiest way is to set both `table.maintanable` and `table.tablestyle`'s `border` to `none`  because both of the them are tables which have contents inside so if you don't set any of them's borders  to `none` will show borders around its children

Comment: Hm, `.tablestyle`'s border is now hidden, but `.maintable` is still there, even with both set to none.  I don't get what I am missing...